# Using promises with download module

Tags: node.js, download, promise, bluebird

I am using bluebird for promises.

I am trying to promisify the [download module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/download).

Here is my implementation:

```
Promise  = require('bluebird'),
download = require('download');

var methodNameToPromisify = ["download"];

function EventEmitterPromisifier(originalMethod) {
    // return a function
    return function promisified() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        // Needed so that the original method can be called with the correct receiver
        var self = this;
        // which returns a promise
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // We call the originalMethod here because if it throws,
            // it will reject the returned promise with the thrown error
            var emitter = originalMethod.apply(self, args);

            emitter
                .on("response", function(data) {
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .on("data ", function(data) {
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .on("error", function(err) {
                    reject(err);
                })
                .on("close", function() {
                    resolve();
                });
        });
    };
};
download = { download: download };
Promise.promisifyAll(download, {
    filter: function(name) {
        return methodNameToPromisify.indexOf(name) > -1;
    },
    promisifier: EventEmitterPromisifier
});
```

Then using it:

```
return download.downloadAsync(fileURL, copyTo, {});
```

My problem is that it doesn't download all of the files (I have a list sent to this   function), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it intentional that (a) `download = { download: download };` overwrites `download = require('download');`, and (b) `.on("data ", ...)` has that space in it?

Comment: My bad, I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An emitter does emit *multiple* data events, one for every chunk it receives. However, a represents only *one* future value, in your case you want that to be the complete response.

`resolve` is supposed to be called only once, to fulfill the promise with the passed value, which is then settled. Further calls will have no effect - and that's why you get only the first parts of your list.

Instead, you will need to accumulate all the data, and when the stream ends you can fulfill the promise with all of it.

```
var Promise  = require('bluebird'),
    download = require('download'),
    Buffer   = require('buffer'); // should be global anyway

exports = {
    downloadAsync: function promisifiedDownload() {
        var args = arguments, self = this;

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // We call the originalMethod here because if it throws,
            // it will reject the returned promise with the thrown error
            var emitter = download.apply(self, args);
            var buffers = [];

            emitter.on("data", function(data) {
                buffers.push(data);
            }).on("error", function(err) {
                reject(err);
            }).on("close", function() {
                resolve(Buffer.concat(buffers));
            });
        });
    };
};
```

<sub>Notice it's quite nonsensical to use `promisifyAll` when you only want to promisify a single method. I've omitted it for simplicity</sub>

You might also listen for the incoming [`response`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_response) object, and attach the `data` listener directly to it. You can then use the [`end` event](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) instead of `close`.

Comment: Although the example in the Angular documentation spells it out in full (as above), presumably `.on("error", reject)` would also work?

Comment: @Bergi, I had to remove the require("buffer") for it to work, thanks! It made things much more clear.

Comment: Doh! I meant "Bluebird" documentation above, not "Angular"

Comment: @agam360: Hm, [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) say "*The `Buffer` class is a global, making it very rare that one would need to ever `require('buffer')`*", but I don't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: I already wondered :-) But if there is a stream example, could you please link it? It might add something to this question.

Comment: Yes I read that too, it makes even more sense after reading it, doesn't it? - I removed the require, I didn't add it. Yet, I still don't know why it fixes it for me.

Comment: My reference is just the Bluebird API, Find "function EventEmitterPromisifier" in the [.promisifyAll() option-promisifier](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#option-promisifier) section.