# Success callback of socket.on() method

Tags: javascript, socket.io, promise

I'd like to make a `GET` request immediately after adding event listener as below.

```
  socket.on('event_of_my_api', function(data){
    console.log('my api is working');
  })
  .then(
    $http.get('path/to/my/api')
  );
```

Where `event_of_my_api` is supposed to be called in my API as:

```
 ### in my api ###
 socket.emit('event_of_my_api', data);
```

Please help me figure out how to do that. I expect a deferred promise is the solution of this.

Comment: I don't think you should do that at all, see also [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29013899/1048572). An evented api shoud not - can not be implemented using a single promise.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me exactly what your question means because you have conflicting words in the title and the first sentence (that indicate a different direction to the question), but here are two possible interpretations/answers.

Assuming the `$http` indicates AngularJS, then if you want to do a GET immediately after you receive a `'event_of_my_api'` event on the socket, then you can do this:

```
socket.on('event_of_my_api', function(data){
    console.log('my api is working');
    $http.get('path/to/my/api').success(...);
});
```

If you want to do a GET immediately after you set up the event handler for the 'event_of_my_api' event without waiting for that event to actually be received, you can do this:

```
socket.on('event_of_my_api', function(data){
    console.log('my api is working');
});
$http.get('path/to/my/api').success(...);
```

If neither of these is the desired direction, then please clarify the question further as to exactly what you want the timing to be.

There seem to be several issues with using promises for this.  First off, `socket.on()` doesn't return a promise and secondly promises are for one-shot operations so using a single promise does not lend itself to events which could occur repeatedly (a promise will only change state once and then it is latched in that state).